# Filtering denied items from collection in ABAC model

Tags: microservices, rbac, abac

I'm trying to the implement ABAC model in my application (microservices architecture) and I have one problem. I have user U which has 'deny' permission for one item X of collection CollectionX. And I don't understand, how I can implement the next situation - User U is getting all items from CollectionX without item X.
How I can implement this situation in the ABAC model?

Answer (score 1):

In XACML (ABAC standard), the natural way is to use the [Multiple Decision profile (MDP) with repeated categories](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/multiple/v1.0/cs02/xacml-3.0-multiple-v1.0-cs02.html#_Toc388943334) (multiple < Attributes > with same Category in a single XACML Request). Provided that the PDP supports MDP (e.g. [AuthzForce](https://github.com/authzforce/core)), your PEP can make a XACML Request as follows (simplified form here for conciseness, not the actual XACML):

- Subject category (< Attributes >) / subject-id = the user identity, e.g. user U (< Attribute >)
- Resource category (< Attributes >) / resource-id = item 1 (< Attribute > with IncludeInResult=true)
- Resource category (< Attributes >) / resource-id = item 2 (< Attribute > with IncludeInResult=true)
- ... etc. for all items in CollectionX

So in the same XACML Request, you are repeating the < Attributes > element of the resource category with a resource-id < Attribute > (with IncludeInResult=true) for each item in the Collection.

The PDP will process that as multiple XACML requests:

- Request 1: Subject category / subject-id = U; resource category / resource-id = item 1 (IncludeInResult=true)
- Request 2: Subject category / subject-id = U; resource category / resource-id = item 2 (IncludeInResult=true)
- ... etc. for all items in Collection X

... and reply a XACML < Response > with multiple < Result >s, one for each individual Request above, including only the Attributes with IncludeInResult=true (i.e. the resource-id in this case):

- Result 1: Decision=Permit, Attributes: resource category / resource-id = item 1
- Result 2: Decision=Permit, Attributes: resource category / resource-id = item 2
- ...
- **Result N: Decision=Deny, Attributes: resource category / resource-id = item X**
- ...
- ... etc. for all items in Collection X

You can do this in XML or JSON as long as the PDP supports the JSON Profile of XACML (e.g. [AuthzForce](https://github.com/authzforce/core)).

If the PDP is remote, I strongly recommend to cache the decision results in the PEP.

Comment: That is, I need to check every element of the collection when they try to get it from the collection?

Comment: Not exactly. With this method, the PEP can know the permissions for all elements at once (in a single XACML response from the PDP), before the user tries to get one of them. If this is in a GUI, this way you could filter out the denied element(s) (only one in your case) from the view so that the user doesn't even see them/it.